# JavaScript/Nodejs : ajax POST request not passing object to backend

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm attempting to post a JSON object to my server, but when I console log `req.body` it shows an empty object. Here's my code:

```
var submitRecipe = () => {

    let recipe = {alias: null, description: null, instructions: null};
    recipe.alias = document.getElementById('alias').value;
    recipe.description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    recipe.instruction = document.getElementById('instructions').value;

    postRequest("/createrecipe", recipe, (xhr) => {
        console.log("Hello!" + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    })
};
var postRequest = (url, data, callback = undefined) => {

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        //Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log("testing"); 
            return callback(200 , xhr.responseText);
        }else{
            return callback(400, xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', url)
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

**Node**

```
createRecipe = function(req, res){

    console.log(req.body);
}
```

I'm using express to transfer the server information, and I am using `bodyParser.json()`. From there, I just call the controller with the following:

**express**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var server = express();

var recipeController = require("./controllers/recipeController");

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));


server.post("/createrecipe", recipeController.createRecipe);
```

The `createRecipe` function just console logs the information, but as stated before, `req.body` is an empty object. All tips are appreciated.

Comment: are you using express.js? if so is bodyParer setup properly?

Comment: Cud you post more of your node.js code then?

Comment: to follow on @Iceman's comment, ensure you've set up body-parser to use JSON and not urlencoded.

Comment: @zim he said he has set it up. "`I am using bodyParser.json()`". So, I think we need the full code to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @Iceman I've made the edits to show my back end code and all the code I am using in express.

Comment: @user5854440 found the issue, content type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XHR expects your data to be encoded or packed in whatever way you expect it to be send unlike other library wrappers like jQuery or Angular Ajax wrapper functions.
Also`body-parser`middleware was not identifying the Content-type and was not activating for the required request.

Simply `JSON.stringify` your json data

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and add the `application/json` MIME type as `xhr`'s `content-type` header.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

Also, If you want to use `url-encoded` do the encoding of your data before attaching and add the corresponding header content type.

***My full test code (for reference purposes):***

**Server** (`testServer.js`):

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var server = express();

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

server.post("/createrecipe", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var resp = {server: "hello world", dataReceived: req.body};
    res.json(resp);
});

server.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/testClient.html");
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running");
})
```

**Client** (`testClient.html`):

```
<input type="text" id="alias" value="a">
<input type="text" id="description" value="b">
<input type="text" id="instructions" value="c">
<button onclick="submitRecipe()"> TEST</button>
<script>
var submitRecipe = () => {

    let recipe = {alias: null, description: null, instructions: null};
    recipe.alias = document.getElementById('alias').value;
    recipe.description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    recipe.instructions = document.getElementById('instructions').value;

    postRequest("/createrecipe", recipe, (status, xhr) => {
        var data = (JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        console.log(data.dataReceived);
    })
};
var postRequest = (url, dataObj, callback = undefined) => {
    //--------------Added line--------------------
    var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
    //--------------Added line--------------------
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        //Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            return callback(200 , xhr);
        }else if(xhr.status == 400){
            return callback(400, xhr);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', url)
    //--------------Added line--------------------
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    //--------------Added line--------------------
    xhr.send(data);


}
</script>
```

Comment: Body parser is not the problem, as I had it set up as stated.

Comment: @user5854440 ok. missd that!!

Comment: @user5854440 I have undeleted the answer, this is the solution. the problem was the body parser not identifying the content type, so added the header, plus I also stringified the data before sending.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added both the `JSON.stringify` function and the `xhr.setRequestHeader` with the proper `MIME` type, and it works now. Another shout out to how readable your changes were.